# The system cannot find the path specified (Java Development Kit)

Tags: java, android, cordova

I just started working with Cordova/PhoneGap and when I want to use the command "cordova run android" on my newly created application, it goes somewhat like this:

```
C:\Users\tobbog\Desktop\MyNewApp>cordova run android
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\tobbog\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_144
The system cannot find the path specified
```

However, the two paths above are both perfectly like that in my Environmental Variables. How can it be that it doesn't find the path?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Remove android by the below command

```
cordova platform rm android
```

Then add the version 5 by the below command

```
cordova platform add android@~5
```

That should help!

Comment: Well, unfortunately I cannot downgrade to android 5 and need to use 6.2.3. I would really want to know why android 6 is having this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to place the paths in quotation marks " ", since it's possible the space in "Program Files" is throwing it off, I know this happens often when trying to run certain programs via command line that take file arguments. So maybe write it like this:

```
C:\Users\tobbog\Desktop\MyNewApp>cordova run android
ANDROID_HOME="C:\Users\tobbog\AppData\Local\Android\sdk"
JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_144"
```

Can't be 100% sure though as I'm unfamiliar with what that program expects (cordova) and other options that may be supplied to it! You could always try checking the readme or documentation related to that program, it probably shows some examples as to how to run something similar.

See how it even changes in the Stack Overflow text formatting? It's possible once it hits that white space after Files (in C:\Program Files) that it's ignoring the rest of the path, so basically you're trying to specify this path for JAVA_HOME:

```
C:\Program
```

And that's it! Would explain why it can't find that path since you probably don't have just a "Program" directory!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my problem! The problem was that I installed and uninstalled the Android Development Kit before. During the uninstal, it didn't delete all of the folders so that I had to delete them manually before installing Android again.